# After updating Purchase table I want to automatically update my Stock Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2014-express, sql-server-2016-express

I am developing Stock Management System. I have to tables like this.

`tblPurchase` Table

```
PurchaseId  |  ItemCode  |   ItemName    | Quantity |
-----------------------------------------------------
 1          |  IMT0003   | Dell Laptop   | 30       |
-----------------------------------------------------
 2          |  IMT0004   | Samsung Phone | 2        |
-----------------------------------------------------
 3          |  IMT0003   | Dell Laptop   | 5        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

`tblProductStock` Table

```
    ItemCode  |   ItemName    | Quantity |
    --------------------------------------
    IMT0003   | Dell Laptop   | 35       |
    --------------------------------------
    IMT0004   | Samsung Phone | 2        |
    --------------------------------------
```

Now I want to doing something like this. now `tblPurchase` table Dell Laptop quantity is 35. And `tblProductStock` also same. Now I return 5 Dell laptop back. Now I want to Update my `tblPurchase` table `PurchaseId` 1 is 25 or `PurchaseId` 3 is to 0. Because I returned 5 item back. I don't care about which `purchaseid`. if I deduct from 30. its should be 25. or if I deduct form `purchaseId` 3 . its should be 0.

And my `tblProductStock` table also should be change according to the `tblPurchase` Table Quantities.Its mean now my `tblProductStock` table dell laptop must be 30. To achieve this target we can use update query like this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_productstock_table_when_updating_purchasequantity] 
ON [dbo].[tblPurchase]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE ps
    SET Quantity = ps.Quantity
    FROM tblProductStock ps JOIN
         (SELECT i.ItemCode, SUM(quantity) as quantity
          FROM tblPurchase i
          GROUP BY i.itemCode
         ) i
         ON ps.ItemCode = i.ItemCode;
END
```

But my problem is not this. this is work as expected. Imagine my `tblPurchase` Table dell laptop quantity is 30. I sell one laptop. not my `tblProductStock` table dell laptop is 29. not 30. Now I return 5 dell laptops form `tblPurchase` table. Now my purchase quantity should me 25. And my `tblProductStock` table must be 24. because I sold one item. to achieve this targer i can use following update statement.

```
UPDATE ps
    SET Quantity = i.quantity - ps.Quantity
    FROM tblProductStock ps JOIN
         (SELECT i.ItemCode, SUM(quantity) as quantity
          FROM tblPurchase i
          GROUP BY i.itemCode
         ) i
         ON ps.ItemCode = i.ItemCode;
```

But how can I using this two update query with trigger. if I use both is same trigger its get wrong value. because quantity is same in both table. i want to update `tblProductStock` table. but my `tblProductStock` table quantity is 29 and purchase is 30 . after i return 5 now my `tblPurchase` 25 and my `tblProductStock` should be 24. thats why i am asking this questions.  Somebody can rewrite this code please send me. I try to solve this more than 100 times. still not solve this problem.

Comment: Your last code should just work.  For a return, the quantity should be negative.  For purchases, positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to update your Stock table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempPurchase
(   ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
    ItemCode VARCHAR (10) ,
    Quantity INT );

CREATE TABLE #TempSold
(   ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
    ItemCode VARCHAR (10) ,
    Quantity INT );

CREATE TABLE #TempStock
(   ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
    ItemCode VARCHAR (10) ,
    Quantity INT );

INSERT INTO #TempPurchase ( ItemCode ,
                            Quantity )
VALUES ( 'IMT0003', 25 ) ,
       ( 'IMT0004', 2 ) ,
       ( 'IMT0003', 5 );

INSERT #TempSold ( ItemCode ,
                   Quantity )
VALUES ( 'IMT0003', 2 );

INSERT INTO #TempStock ( ItemCode ,
                         Quantity )
VALUES ( 'IMT0003', 30 ) ,
       ( 'IMT0004', 2 );


CREATE TABLE #FinalData
(   ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
    ItemCode VARCHAR (10) ,
    Quantity INT );

INSERT #FinalData ( ItemCode ,
                    Quantity )
       SELECT   ts.ItemCode ,
                ISNULL (( SUM (tp.Quantity) - ts2.Quantity ), ts.Quantity) AS quantity
       FROM     #TempStock AS ts
                LEFT JOIN #TempPurchase AS tp ON tp.ItemCode = ts.ItemCode
                LEFT JOIN #TempSold AS ts2 ON ts2.ItemCode = ts.ItemCode
       GROUP BY ts.ItemCode ,
                ts2.Quantity ,
                ts.Quantity;

UPDATE ts
SET    ts.Quantity = fd.Quantity
FROM   #FinalData AS fd
       INNER JOIN #TempStock AS ts ON ts.ItemCode = fd.ItemCode;

DROP TABLE #TempStock
DROP TABLE #TempPurchase
DROP TABLE #TempSold
DROP TABLE #FinalData
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question. In here all tables are temp tables. Am I correct? After updating all record is deleting know

Comment: I worked with temp tables to just to show you an example. You will work with your existing tables in your case. And, records will not be deleted after update in above case. It will only be wiped out after the session is over.